# line integral: anticlockwise parametrisation in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, vector-analysis

Consider $\gamma$ given by the sides of the triangle with vertices $(0,0,1)^t$, $(0,1,0)^t$ and $(1,0,0)^t$. So $\gamma$ runs through the sides of the triangle. Let $f(x,y,z)=(y,xz,x^2)$.

I want to calculate $\int_\gamma f(\gamma(t))\cdot\dot\gamma(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.

So I have to calculate this integral for every side of the triangle.

I know I have to go anticlockwise. So do we get $\gamma_1(s)=(1,0,0)^ts+(0,1,0)^t(1-s)$ or $\gamma_1(s)=(0,1,0)^ts+(1,0,0)^t(1-s)$ for $s\in[0,1]$? From where do you consider the "anticlockwise direction"?

I would guess we are looking from $(0,0,0)^t$. But if you're looking from outside the triangle we get the other way around.

I am a bit confussed. In one or two dimensions it's easy to see but in higher dimensions not. So from where are you looking at the triangle?

Comment: If you are told to calculate the integral in the second line of the question, they at least should tell you what $f$ and $\gamma$ are.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I forgot, I've fixed it. Does it help?

Comment: For line integrals of functions, orientation does not matter. It is for line integral for vector fields that orientation is important. In addition, counter-clockwise has no meaning in space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three points in ${\mathbb R}^3$ determine a triangle $T$, but not its "positive normal", nor the sense of direction of $\gamma:=\partial T$. Using Occam's razor I'd assume that the intended orientation of $T$, resp., $\gamma$ is such that $\gamma:=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$ with
$$\eqalign{\gamma_1(s)&=(0,0,1)(1-s)+(0,1,0)s,\cr
\gamma_2(s)&=(0,1,0)(1-s)+(1,0,0)s,\cr
\gamma_3(s)&=(1,0,0)(1-s)+(0,0,1)s.\cr}
$$
The induced orientation of the surface of $T$ would then be such that the positive normal points to the origin, i.e., one has $n={1\over\sqrt{3}}(-1,-1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, "counterclockwise" without further qualification means "counterclockwise from above", i.e. from the positive $z$-direction. However, this should really be made explicit in the setup in order to avoid this type of confusion, especially since "counterclockwise from above" doesn't make sense for all types of curves in $\mathbb R^3$. You should insist that whoever gave you this question be clearer.

Comment: What is the counterclockwise orientation of the triangle with vertices $(0,0,1)$, $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$?

Comment: @Taladris, Counterclockwise doesn't make sense in that setting, which is why the phrase "counterclockwise" should not be used without further qualification.